# how to convert from html to php

Tags: php, html

I have to generate the next available ID which is primary key in the table, but for that I have to convert from html to PHP within the value attribute in an input tag.

This does not work since the PHP file hangs in between and doesn't allow full page to load.

I have tried this code:

```
<input type="number" id="id" class="textbox" name="s_id" onkeyup="showAvailableId(this.value)" min="10000" max="999999" 
value ="<?php $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'project_db');
   if($mysqli->connect_error) {
        exit('Could not connect');
       }
   $sql = 'SELECT student_id from students WHERE student_id = 11120';
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();
   $stmt->bind_result($result);          
   $stmt->fetch();
   $stmt->close();

   if ($result != NULL){
          echo ++$result;
   }?>" required><label id="demo"></label>
```

Comment: You should run the query and return the results into a variable which can then be echoed in your HTML.

Comment: well.. i am echoing the result  on second last line

Comment: Yeah, but your code is a mess. No one is doing what you're doing as it makes things hard to manage and maintain.

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs"? Do you mean that the script takes too long to execute?

Comment: Your SQL string is fixed?  Where is $stmt declared?

Comment: stmt->execute(); thats where my stmt get declared the main thing is how to run php within that value attribute

Comment: For example you can pass the value of the input to a php file when you submit the form

Comment: Why do you need to generate the next available ID? This makes me suspicious. Are you not using an auto increment field in the database? The application should not be telling the database what ID to use for a new row...this can lead to situations where two users request the next ID simultaneously, and when they come to insert a record with that ID, the second user who submits finds the ID is already taken in the database. And then either the app crashes because the developer never thought of this, or the poor user has to keep submitting until they are lucky and get a free ID.

Comment: @ADyson the problem is not with the id i want to convert from html writing to php and want to fire query **CAN I DO THAT**

Comment: Also, not that I'm very keen to encourage this practice, but are you ever assigning $result? you say  $stmt->bind_result($result); and ++$result but where do you first instantiate and assign that variable?

Comment: Yes you can, but you're not doing it properly. You said "stmt->execute(); thats where my stmt get declared " ...no, that's you trying to execute a function of the $stmt object...but nowhere do I see you _create_ that object. You need to run the [prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) function first which will parse your query and output a statement object, which you can then execute. I see the accepted answer also suggested a slightly different way of doing it, which is also fine.

Comment: But I still question why you want to know this next ID? What will you use it for, once you output it? I can't think of a good reason to want to know it. As I and others have said, if you're using it for the purpose of later creating a new row with that ID, then **don't** - think again and use an auto increment field instead, which is the reliable, concurrency-proof, industry-standard way to generate new unique IDs in your database. I say this to potentially stop you wasting time on a bad feature.

Comment: Montion Seconded

Comment: Thnx for your suggestion @ADyson 
If any doubt will be there then i will ask again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not quite understand the need, I would use mysql's auto increment and if there is an insert before this code snippet, I would use "Select Last ID".
But you must be careful about this way of generating the ID.
You must submit the form without the ID and generate the ID within MySQL

```
    <?php 
  $nextID = array("student_id"=>0);

  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'project_db'); 

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  $sql = 'SELECT MAX(student_id) + 1 AS student_id from students';  
  if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $nextID = $row[0]['student_id'];
    }  
    $result->close();
  }
  $mysqli->close();

?>

<input type="number" id="id" class="textbox" name="s_id" onkeyup="showAvailableId(this.value)" min="10000" max="999999" 
value="<?php echo $result['student_id']; ?>" required><label id="demo"></label>
```

Comment: this is not a great solution as by the time your query executes it may (and in a site of any reasonable size almost certainly would) already be out of date by the time the form comes back

Comment: It's not, as I said, it's not the way it should work! But the source corrects the query mode in db. Note that the $ sql variable is not used anywhere.

Comment: @Rodrigo Rea i got my solution with some modification in your code. you should modify 1st while echoing it should be $nextID['student_id'] and 2nd while assinging $nextID= $row[0]['student_id'] make it $nextID=['student_id'=>row[0]] and rest of the things are good btw thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to do this, what if 100 people all run this code at the same time, they all get the same next available id but then only 1 of them is actually able to do anything with it because it's a primary key, so whoever submits the form first get's the id but everyone else returns false, and they all get stuck in a loop until enough people give up or wait long enough to submit the form.

You should re-think what you are trying to achieve